# not able to activate plugin 'Sensei Pro (WC Paid Courses)' due to fatal error "Class 'Sensei_Temporary_User' not found" in plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Wordpress plugin 'Sensei Pro (WC Paid Courses)' was working fine but suddenly it stopped working and made the site crash. I found the issue to be of plugin 'Sensei Pro (WC Paid Courses)'.

issue: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Sensei_Temporary_User' not found in /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/plugins/sensei-lms/includes/class-sensei.php:518 Stack trace: #0 /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/plugins/sensei-lms/includes/class-sensei.php(352): Sensei_Main->initialize_global_objects() #1 /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/plugins/sensei-lms/includes/class-sensei.php(313): Sensei_Main->init() #2 /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/plugins/sensei-lms/includes/class-sensei.php(373): Sensei_Main->__construct() #3 /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/plugins/sensei-lms/sensei-lms.php(110): Sensei_Main::instance() #4 /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/plugins/sensei-lms/sensei-lms.php(116): Sensei() #5 /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/woothemes-sen in /wp-content/plugins/woothemes-sensei/plugins/sensei-lms/includes/class-sensei.php on line 518`

I renamed the plugin to make the site work but now when I try to activate the plugin the above issue causes plugin not to be activated.

I googled for the solution but till now no success. Can anyone suggest what exactly is the issue and how can I proceed further.
Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Paid plugins should usually come with support from the plugin provider.